# Templatized Storing Multiple Different Types In std::vector

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, vector, casting

thank you all for your time I really appreciate it.

There exists a need to store multiple variables of different types in a std::vector using a templatized fashion. To use the following functions the programmer must be aware of which order they stored the variables and how many variables were stored.

```
class _NetVar {};
```

A sub class is created to hold the actual variable:

```
template <class VARTYPE> class NetVar : public _NetVar
{
private:
    VARTYPE Var;
    NetVar(VARTYPE Value)
    {
        Var = Value;
    }
};
```

A vector is created of the base helper class

```
std::vector<_NetVar> DataVec;
```

Data is put into the vector like so:

```
template <class DATATYPE> void AddData(DATATYPE AddData)
{
    DataVec.push_back(NetVar<DATATYPE>(AddData));
}
```

Data is pulled out of the vector here, an internal variable holds the current position of the vector and is incremented each time a variable is requested:

```
template <class DATATYPE> DATATYPE GetData()
{
    NetVar<DATATYPE> Temp = PacketData[VecPos];

    return Temp.Var;
    ++VecPos;
}
```

The previous function is where the trouble arises, it is possible to recognize the sub class as it's base class but is it possible to recognize the base class as one of it's sub classes?

Here is how the code is being used:

```
AddData<int>(32);
AddData<bool>(true);
AddData<std::string>("Test");

auto Var1 = GetData<int>();
auto Var2 = GetData<bool>();
auto Var3 = GetData<std::string>();
```

When GetData is called an exception is thrown:

```
'initializing' : cannot convert from '_NetVar' to 'NetVar<DATATYPE>'
```

If anyone can help me with this it would be greatly appreciated, thank you again for your time.

Note: External libraries such as Boost need to be avoided.

Comment: "*Note: External libraries such as Boost need to be avoided.*" Why? It already contains multiple well-documented, well-tested libraries to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Boost is a very large bloated library, I don't want to use it for this single feature which I can accomplish on my own, not to mention the serialization library I'm using already supports std::shared_ptr thank you though :)

Comment: Boost is a _collection_ of libraries, not a single, monolithic library. If one only needs e.g. Boost.Serialization, then one could extract only Boost.Serialization and discard the other libraries. And saying that you can reimplement the functionality of Boost.Serialization on your own is to imply that you are quite the expert!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector should be:

```
std::vector<_NetVar *> DataVec;
```

or a high level pointer

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<_NetVar> > DataVec;
```

so that you can store instances of the child classes instead of [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) them to the base class.

On GetData you will need to upcast the pointer retrieved from the vector.

---

### Edit: Adding a full blown working code

Example working on [ideone](http://ideone.com/0wcMc1), had to fiddle with the permissions a bit.

and the example goes with some comments added.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
class _NetVar {};

template <class VARTYPE> 
class NetVar : public _NetVar
{
private:
    VARTYPE Var;
public:
    NetVar(VARTYPE Value)
    {
        Var = Value;
    }
};
```

Note that I changed NetVar<> constructor and Var attribute to be public... AddData and GetData needed to access it.

Not sure if in your example you had some virtual methods on _NetVar (in which case the [static_pointer_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) below could be a [dynamic_pointer_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast))

Related to that, you might want to veriy that the destructors for NetVar (and not only the destructors for _NetVar) are being called (checked on ideone, they work in my example because I'm using `std::make_shared<NetVar<XX> >(...)`)

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<_NetVar> > DataVec;
int VecPos;
```

Added this global variables for the functions below to work.

```
template <class DATATYPE> void AddData(DATATYPE AddData)
{
    DataVec.push_back(std::make_shared<NetVar<DATATYPE> >(AddData));
}
```

So here we create a `shared_ptr` with new object `NetVar<DATATYPE>` and push it into the vector.

```
template <class DATATYPE> DATATYPE GetData()
{
    std::shared_ptr<_NetVar> content = DataVec[VecPos];
    std::shared_ptr<NetVar<DATATYPE> > Temp = std::static_pointer_cast<NetVar<DATATYPE> >(content);
    ++VecPos;

    return Temp->Var;
}
```

Here, the content of the vector is `std::shared_ptr<_NetVar>` so that's what we get. That shared_ptr needs to be upcasted to the right kind of shared_ptr

Now there's a concern that you must know the right type to upcast to, otherwise is undefined behaviour. If you had virtual methods you could use dynamic_pointer_cast and then perform a check for null... but that has some [performance penalties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7579250/308705)

```
int main() {

    AddData<int>(32);
    AddData<bool>(true);
    AddData<std::string>("Test");

    auto Var1 = GetData<int>();
    auto Var2 = GetData<bool>();
    auto Var3 = GetData<std::string>();

    std::cout << Var1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << Var2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << Var3 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Finally testing and printing the resuls.

Comment: The vector is being serialized and networked to a remote machine, that being said I believe I am unable to use pointers within the vector itself here since a pointer only points to an address in memory?

Comment: @KKlouzal Check that, because in your vector you're not storing what you think you're storing. A derived class *includes* the base class, when you're storing an instance of a derived class in your vector you are **copying** the part of the base class and *losing* the rest. Look at the *slicing* link in the answer. You would need a serialization method that take into account the child classes.

Comment: I'm using Cereal for serialization, I just double checked and they support std::shared_ptr so I'll give that a try! Could you please edit your answer with a quick example how the GetData function might look using std::shared_ptr it's confusing me a bit. Thank you so much!

Comment: @KKlouzal I've just edited, including complete working code and reference to [that code in ideone](http://ideone.com/0wcMc1)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I don't even know how to express my gratitude towards you right now, thank you so very much!

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to get rid of `_NetVar` and use [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html), as in:

```
std::vector<boost::any> DataVec;

template<class T>
void AddData(T data)
{ DataVec.emplace_back(std::move(data)); }

template<class T>
T GetData()
{ return boost::any_cast<T>(DataVec[VecPos++]); }

AddData(32);
AddData(true);
AddData(std::string("test"));

auto Var1 = GetData<int>();
auto Var2 = GetData<bool>();
auto Var3 = GetData<std::string>();
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `boost::any` keeps objects on the free store.

Comment: I do not want to use boost but I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: @iavr - you cannot solve his problem without keeping objects on the free store.

Comment: @Nevin Well, depending on object size, you can if you reserve a (compile-time) specified space on the stack - similarly to "short string optimization".

Comment: That assumes you know all the types ahead of time, in which case you can just use Boost.Variant.  Type punning (which the small object optimization requires) is fairly tricky to get right if you are coding it by hand.